# Passing parameter properly in an Ant task

Tags: ant

I have an Ant build file named 'prepare.all.xml' which has the following line:

```
<import file="${build.config.dir}/prepare.tools.config.xml" description="Standard tool configurations"/>
```

I am trying to run this build file and the command that I gave is -

```
ant -buildfile=prepare.all.xml
```

This threw me an error and the error is:

```
C:\CIA-TestFramework\build-config\prepare.all.xml:6: Cannot find C:\CIA-TestFramework\buildconfig\${build.config.dir}\prepare.tools.config.xml imported from C:\CIA-TestFramework\build-config\prepare.all.xml
```

Now the file 'prepare.tools.config.xml' is located in the directory- C:\CIA-TestFramework\build-config\

What should be the command to make this run properly?

Comment: Sounds like you are missing the definition of the build.config.dir property!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property build.config.dir is not set.
If you want to set it in commandline use :

```
ant -buildfile=prepare.all.xml -Dbuild.config.dir=whatever
```

see [Ant manual Running Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#options) for details